# Is there a better way to write this nested for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a for loop which takes the contents of a 2D matrix and rotates them 90 degrees to the write like so:

```
|2|3|4|5|
---------
|7|6|8|9|

to:

|7|2|
-----
|6|3|
-----
|8|4|
-----
|9|5|

my code so far is:

rotated = []

#you may change matrix as you want
matrix=[[1 , 2 , 3] ,[ 4 , 5 , 6]]

# append a new matrix for each col      
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    rotated.append([])
    # append the last up till the 1st item to the 1st list in our new rotated list
    for j in range(len(matrix) - 1, -1, -1):
        rotated[i].append(matrix[j][i])
print(rotated)
```

Comment: Just use `zip()` `list(zip(*reversed(l)))` gives you `[(7, 2), (6, 3), (8, 4), (9, 5)]`

Comment: in last line ...you should use rotated or define rotate to make code run

Answer (score 2):

This is probably cheating, but.. it works ;)

```
arr = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5],
    [7, 6, 8, 9]
]

rotated = [ list(values) for values in zip(*reversed(arr)) ]
print(rotated)
```